# Permission elevation from VBScript

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

We run Dynamics GP. Because of the way it stores forms/reports, I need to have some install scripts that copy a .SET file into the program directory. This can be done manually, but it's much quicker to just have a user run an installer script which installs the proper files for them.

I've been building a VBScript installer that copies the necessary files around. The tricky part is that some clients are running Windows XP, and some are running Windows 7 (or even 8). UAC is enabled, so permissions come into play.

The way I've tried to do it is by blindly attempting to copy the files, and if a permission error is detected, it relaunches the script with administrator permissions. Where we've run into problems is some (all?) Windows 7 machines have virtualized file/registry writes enabled, so when the script tries to copy files into C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010, it silently fails and copies them to the user's AppData\Local\VirtualStore directory. This doesn't work properly with GP.

So what I need to do is have the script copy the files to C:\Program Files (not the VirtualStore directory), and elevate permissions only if necessary. If I have it elevate across the board, this causes the Windows XP machines to simply pop up a cryptic "Run As" dialog box when launching the script.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim WSHShell, FSO, Desktop, DesktopPath
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Desktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
DesktopPath = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Desktop)

'Set working directory to directory the script is in.
'This ends up being C:\Windows\System32 if the script is
'started from ShellExecute, or a link in an email, thus breaking
'relative paths.
WSHShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder

On Error Resume Next

If FSO.FolderExists("C:\Program Files (x86)") Then
    WScript.Echo "Installing 64-bit."
    FSO.CopyFile "64-bit\*.set", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\", True
    FSO.CopyFile "64-bit\*.lnk", DesktopPath, True
ElseIf FSO.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\Mekorma MICR") Then
    WScript.Echo "Installing 32-bit (with MICR)."
    FSO.CopyFile "32-bit MICR\*.set", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\", True
    FSO.CopyFile "32-bit MICR\*.lnk", DesktopPath, True 
Else
    WScript.Echo "Installing 32-bit."
    FSO.CopyFile "32-bit\*.SET", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\", True
    FSO.CopyFile "32-bit\*.lnk", DesktopPath, True
End If

If Err.Number = 70 Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """" , "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Source & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Else
    MsgBox "Installed successfully."
End If
```

In summary: How do I have a VBScript elevate permissions *without* causing XP to stall at a "Run As" dialog box, and *without* causing Windows 7 to copy the files to AppData\Local\VirtualStore instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is the simplest way to do it.

1. Check OS version.
2. If it's not XP or 2003 (I don't anticipate this running on anything older), re-execute with elevation.

Here's the code block I added to the beginning of the script:

```
Dim OSList, OS, UAC
UAC = False
If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
    If WScript.Arguments.Item(0) = "elevated" Then UAC = True
End If

If Not(UAC) Then
    Set OSList = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each OS In OSList
        If InStr(1, OS.Caption, "XP") = 0 And InStr(1, OS.Caption, "Server 2003") = 0 Then
            CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ elevated" , "", "runas", 1
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Looks like you answer yourself, but I'll test if the current logged user has admin rights, instead of Win version, and elevate if only needs.

Answer (score 5):

Improved on @db2 answer:

- real elevation testing, without depending on passed arguments
- passes all original arguments to the elevated script
- uses the same host of the initial script: `wscript.exe`, `cscript.exe`, whatever

**Code:**

```
Set OSList = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each OS In OSList
    If InStr(1, OS.Caption, "XP") = 0 And InStr(1, OS.Caption, "Server 2003") = 0 Then
        With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            IsElevated = .Run("cmd.exe /c ""whoami /groups|findstr S-1-16-12288""", 0, true) = 0
            If Not IsElevated Then
                Dim AllArgs
                For Each Arg In WScript.Arguments
                    If InStr( Arg, " " ) Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
                    AllArgs = AllArgs & " " & Arg
                Next
                Command = """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & AllArgs
                With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                    .ShellExecute WScript.FullName, " //nologo " & Command, "", "runas", 1
                    WScript.Echo WScript.FullName & " //nologo " & Command
                End With
                WScript.Quit
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

' Place code to run elevated here
```