# Creating an elevated object

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, admin

I have an VBScript that is creating a MS Word object.
But I need the word object itself to be elevated.

I am trying to use the object to do certain tasks but they currently failing/not satisfactory results because of insufficient privileges

`Set obj­Word = CreateObject(“Word.Application”)`

Any idea how to create a elevated object?

Comment: What task requiring elevation do you need to do? Normally, elevation is not required when automating Word, unless you want to save your document to a restricted location. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Basically getting all the window objects, I changed the above scenario. The script is not elevated. Because of this, the returned window list does not include elevated applications.

Comment: The solution is to start your VBScript from an elevated prompt or to request elevation and restart your script (along the lines of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34646253/40347)

Comment: Ok so those are not solutions. Just alternative methods. If you put this as the answer I can mark it answered.