# Files are not copied into zip file using VBS code

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a zip file and copy files into it via VBS code. When I run the below VBS code, it is running successfully. Outcome.zip is getting created, but no files are copied

```
Here is my code :

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\apace-jmeter-3\bin\Results\outcome.zip", 2, True)
ts.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String( 18, Chr(0) )
Set fso = nothing
Set ts = nothing

WScript.Sleep 5000


Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace("C:\apace-jmeter-3\bin\Results\outcome.zip")
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace("C:\Users\chitra.balasubramani\Desktop\Mail")
DestFldr.CopyHere SrcFldr
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy folder contents to a created .zip file: 'file not found or no read permissions'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699767/copy-folder-contents-to-a-created-zip-file-file-not-found-or-no-read-permissi)

Comment: I tried closing the zip file. Still it is showing access denied error

Comment: [edit] your code to include that call and the exact error message.

Comment: There are two possible files that could be locked here. Have you worked out whether it's the zip file or the source folder that is locked?

Comment: Not the source folder. If i try to copy to another folder instead of zip, it is working fine. Problem should be with zip file. I have added code to close it. Still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Files copying with `.CopyHere` method is asynchronous, you should add compressed files count check before script exits so that copying will not be interrupted. Take a look at the below example:

```
sDest = "C:\apace-jmeter-3\bin\Results\outcome.zip"
sSrc = "C:\Users\chitra.balasubramani\Desktop\Mail"

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sDest, 2, True).Write _
    "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))

With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oDestFldr = .NameSpace(sDest)
    Set oSrcFldr = .NameSpace(sSrc)
    oDestFldr.CopyHere oSrcFldr.Items
    Do 
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until oDestFldr.Items.Count = oSrcFldr.Items.Count
End With
```

Comment: Tried the above method. Getting access denied error. Tried adding Closing the file. Still access denied error.

Comment: If the dest folder is "Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace("C:\apace-jmeter-3\bin\Results\Temp")", Copy is working. 

If the dest is Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace("C:\apace-jmeter-3\bin\Results\outcome.zip")", getting access denied error.

Comment: @ChitraBalasubramani try to omit the line `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sDest, 2, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, Chr(0))` (just comment it) and create an empty zip file manually before launching the script.

Comment: I have tried copying to the empty zip which was created manually. Getting the same "Access Denied Error". When i try to copy files manually to the empty zip file, it is allowing. Getting error via VB Script

Comment: @ChitraBalasubramani try to run the code elevated, take a look at the solutions e. g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296281/2165759).